# SWT Combo Listener getText() not updated

Tags: java, swt

Hello fellow SWT programmers,

today I wanted to add a Listener to my custom SWT Combo view.
(a bit modified) code:

```
combo.addListener(SWT.ALL, new Listener() {

  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
       //some irrelevant code
       String text = combo.getText();
       System.out.println(text);
}
```

However, as I enter something into the text field, the text that was in the Combo View BEFORE I triggered the event is outputted, meaning that the combo.getText() returns the text it contained before the event was triggered.

How do I solve this issue and get the updated Combo text input within this Listener?
I can't use a ModifyListener, it has to be the Listener interface (since I need to differ between the event types and do stuff accordingly).

Thanks in advance,

forumfresser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SWT.ALL` is not a valid value for `addListener`. As it happens it will be interpreted as `SWT.KeyDown`.

Use `SWT.Modify` to listen for modify events:

```
combo.addListener(SWT.Modify, new Listener() {
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I need this one listener that listens to all events at once.

Comment: There is no way to listen to all events other than adding a listener for each individual event type.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. One final question: For some reason the ModifyListener gets called before the default Listener. However, I need to do some calculations within the Listener before executing the ModifyListener. Is there a way to define Listener Hierarchy/Priority?

Comment: Listeners are called in the order they are added. `addModifyListener` is converted to `addListener(SWT.Modify` internally so the two methods are on the same list.

Comment: It seems like you were not 100% right - I have a custom Listener that implements SelectionListener and ModifyListener. Now I add the one listener like this: `public void setAutoCompleteListener(ComboAutoCompleteListener listener) {
  this.addSelectionListener(listener);
  this.addModifyListener(listener);
 }`, however the Modify Listener gets called first (which I certainly don't want). Any help?

Comment: Listeners of the same type are called in order of adding. For different types of listener the order is defined by the code in the control.